# How do I assign tuple to function parameter and print second element of that tuple?

Tags: python, function, parameters, tuples

Can I have some direction with this?

The instructions in a task I am trying to complete state:

Complete the second_element function to print the second element of tup.
Input for tup: "Jimbo", "David", "Catfish", "Chasm"
The task starts with:

```
def second_element(tup):
```

The code I've tried:

```
def second_element(tup):
    tup = ("Jimbo", "David", "Catfish", "Chasm")
    print(tup[1])
```

and then I call it with:

```
second_element(tup)
```

and then I see the following error:

line 5, in    second_element(tup)
NameError: name 'tup' is not defined

I thought I did pass the tuple to the function parameter.  I'm very new.  Please be delicate, lol.

Comment: `tup = ("Jimbo", "David", "Catfish", "Chasm")` belongs before the call to `second_element`, not in its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just this:

```py
tup = ("Jimbo", "David", "Catfish", "Chasm")

def second_element(tup):
    print(tup[1])

second_element(tup)
```

`Out[1]: "David"`

You needed to define the tuple outside the function.

Comment: Ahh, okay - tup needs to be assigned globally instead of locally for this to work correctly?

Comment: Thank you kindly for the help with this!  BTW, how do I give points to you on here?

Comment: Your question was asking for input, so you needed to build a function that accepted input from outside the function. You can point the upward arrow to the left of my comment, and also the checkmark. Thanks, and welcome to S/O!

Comment: I tried, but I guess I need a rep score of 15 or more to vote.  Ahh well, considering this is my second question on here, I have some work to do to get that rep score higher.  Thanks again!